# Element extends on new line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I'm having some problems with making a wordpress template responsive. I'm using bootstrap for this, however i have 3  elements one after another which occupy too much space so the last one is extended on another line.
Here's a screenshot so you better understand what it does: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1O6h.png

And here's the HTML:

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <section class = "social hidden-xs col-md-6">
                asd
            </section>
            <div class = "row">
                <section class = "user col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-right">
                    <a class = "phone" href = "#">Call us at <strong>810-991-3842</strong></a>
                    <a class = "register" href = "#">Register</a>
                    <a class = "login" href = "#">Log in</a>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.navigation .user a {
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
line-height: 32px;
border-right: 1px solid #ebebeb;
text-indent: 15px;
margin-left: 8px;
padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Basically I want the elements to be resized so they fit on the line. How can I do that with bootstrap?

Comment: Did you try using Bootrap's navigation structures? They might help you avoid any custom CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your code so `col-md-6` is larger (`col-md-12` for instance). It's hard to say with just a teeny snippet given. Bootstrap does have some nav helpers if this needs to be a part of the navbar, specifically for alignment (`.navbar-right`, but you can also use `pull-right`). I would consider converting to use navbar utilities.

Is there a reason why your second section is nested in a row? It might be good to pull that out. For mobile, you could also change the second second into a drop-menu to consolidate register and login.

You could also use a mobile breakpoint to decrease the font size.

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 767px) {
     .user { 
        font-size: 12px;
     }
}
```

This is a rough example.

Comment: I'm interested in decreasing the font size by using a mobile breakpoint. How can I do that?

Comment: I've added the code at the top of my css file and it doesn't work

Comment: Use `.navigation .user a ` instead of just `.user`. We're pretty much going blind because you've provided such limited content.